# Java object destructuring

Tags: java, object, destructuring

In javascript there is object destructuring so we can break down objects and just use the end key if the intermidiate objects are resused multiple times. e.g)

```
const person = {
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: "Marley",
  city: "Space"
}
```

So instead of calling `person.<>` to get each value we can destructure it like this

```
console.log(person.firstName) 
console.log(person.lastName) 
console.log(person.city)
```

Destructured:

```
const { firstName, lastName, city } = person;
```

And call like this:

```
console.log(firstName)
console.log(lastName)
console.log(city)
```

Is there something similar in Java? I have this Java Object that I need to get the value from and have to call long intermediate object names like this:

```
myOuterObject.getIntermediateObject().getThisSuperImportantGetter()
myOuterObject.getIntermediateObject().getThisSecondImportantGetter()
...
```

I would like this destructure it somehow and just call the last method `getThisSuperImportantGetter()`, `getThisSecondImportantGetter()` for cleaner code.

Comment: That *is* how you "destructure" objects in Java. There are various ways you could convert from a string to properties, but there's little point, or you can introduce a jvm scripting language. Either way you'll pay a performance penalty. Or you can get the intermediate object and base your mainline code off that. "Clean" isn't generally associated with Java code when you're reaching into nested objects (and arguably it can be a little sketchy to do so depending on how easily you need to be able to modify/extend your code, e.g., Demeter).

Comment: Java isn't known for being terse or expressive. You may want to look at another JVM language if those qualities are important to you.

Comment: No, it doesn't, but you can call a method with the result of the first getter, then inside that method work with the inner object.

Comment: you can assign the inner object to a 1 letter variable first and then call `a.getThisSuperImportantGetter()`;  `a.getThisSecondImportantGetter();`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Java Language Architect [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) has recently talked about adding destructuring to an upcoming version of Java. Look for the *Sidebar: pattern matching* chapter in his paper:

[Towards Better Serialization](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/serialization.html)

I strongly dislike the current proposal of the syntax, but according to Brian your use case will look like the following (please note, that at this point this is a proposal only and **will not work with any current version of Java**):

```
public class Person {
    private final String firstName, lastName, city;

    // Constructor
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String city) { 
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.city = city;
    }

    // Deconstruction pattern
    public pattern Person(String firstName, String lastName, String city) { 
        firstName = this.firstName;
        lastName = this.lastName;
        city = this.city;
    }
}
```

You should than be able to use that deconstruction pattern for instance in an instanceof check like so:

```
if (o instanceof Person(var firstName, lastName, city)) {
   System.out.println(firstName);
   System.out.println(lastName);
   System.out.println(city);
}
```

Sorry, Brian does not mention any direct destructuring assignment in his examples, and I'm not sure if and how these will be supported.

*On a side note*: I do see the intended similarity to the constructor, but I personally do not like the current proposal that much, because the arguments of the "deconstructor" feel like out-parameters (Brian says as much in his paper). For me this is rather counter-intuitiv in a world where everybody is talking about immutability and making your method parameters `final`.

I would rather like to see Java jump over the fence and support multi-value return types instead. Something along the lines of:

```
    public (String firstName, String lastName, String city) deconstruct() { 
        return (this.firstName, this.lastName, this.city);
    }
```

Comment: Multiple return types comes automatically once you have tuple types and destructuring built in into the language.

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll get `deconstruct` for free when using `public record Person(String firstName, String lastName, String city){}`. I agree that out parameters are a bit odd.

Comment: Just curious: Can you give an example how a `record` might assist with destructuring?

Comment: While the final syntax of the deconstruct declaration is not fixed, it is already given that records will get a default implementation, similar to how they get a default constructor today. So, with the record declaration, the deconstruction into variables matching their components will work out-of-the-box.

Comment: [Record Patterns](https://openjdk.org/jeps/440) are now part of Java 21.
Just as @StefanHaberl I frowned on the syntax first. However it ensures that deep destructuring is possible in a type-safe way, especially in light of type erasure.

Comment: Funny, though, that in 2023 we‘re still talking about type erasure ;)

Answer (score 24):

As far as I know, Java doesn't support this.

Another JVM language called Kotlin does support this

[Kotlin | Destructuring Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html)

Comment: Clojure also supports it, even with nested structures including arrays and maps.

Answer (score 1):

As noted Java does not support destructured assignments like Javascript.  But, [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/), a jvm language, also supports it like so:

```
def (a,b,c) = [10, 20, 'foo']
```

Or with data types like so:

```
def (int i, String j) = [10, 'foo']
```